# memcpy trouble with c

Tags: c, memcpy

everything should be working in this program so far except I am having some issues with  memcpy. The program is supposed to get numbers, sort them, and add them in total. Its supposed to copy the results and store them, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

#define MINIMUM_QUANTITY  2      
#define MAXIMUM_QUANTITY  200            
#define QUIT              0      

void print_heading();
void print_instructions();
int  get_quantity();
void get_data(float *dataStart, int quantity);
void sort_data(float *dataStart, int quantity);
void print_data(float *dataStart, int quantity );
float sum_data(float *dataStart, int quantity);
void print_total(float total);

int main()
{
   int   quantity;
   float *data;

   {
      getData(p_data, quantity);
      sortData(p_data, quantity);
      printData(p_data, quantity);
      printTotal(sum_data(p_data, quantity));


      free(p_data);
   }


   return 0;
}

int quantity()
{
   int choice;

   do
   {
      printf("\nHow many data values are there (%d to %d, %d=quit): ",
             MINIMUM_QUANTITY, MAXIMUM_QUANTITY, QUIT);
      scanf ("%d", &choice);
   }
   while((choice > MINIMUM_QUANTITY && choice < MAXIMUM_QUANTITY)
         && choice != QUIT);
   return choice;
}

void getData(float *dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float *p_data;

   for(data = dataStart; (data - dataStart) <= quantity; data++)
   {
      printf("Enter data value %f: ", data);
      scanf ("%f", data);

   }
   return;
}

void sortData(float *dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float *data,
         *sort, 
         *sortStart,          
         *biggest;    

   for(sort = sortStart; (sort - sortStart) < quantity; sort++) 
   {
      *sort = 0.0f;
      for(data = dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; data++)
      {
         if(*data >= *sort)
         {
            *biggest = *data;
            *sort    = *biggest;
         }
      *biggest = 0.0f;
      }
   }
   memcpy(data, sort, sortStart);     

   free(sort);

   return;
}

void printData(float dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float data;


   for(data = dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; data++)
   {
      printf("                     %.2f", *data);
   }

   return;
}
float sumData(float *dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float *data,
         dataTotal = 0;

   for(data =  dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; pdata++)
      dataTotal += *data;
    return dataTotal;
}

void total(float total)
{
   printf("\n                       %f", total);
   return;
}
```

Comment: for(sort = sortStart; (sort - sortStart) < quantity; sort++) --- sortStart isn't initialized, did you mean to assign it before the loop?

Comment: Also, what is it doing that is wrong? Failing to copy? Or sorting wrong?

Comment: Unable to compile this. Can you give us a compilable example.

Comment: Add output, and point out your specific function which seems erroneous to you.

Comment: What is `p_data`? `getData()` called before declaration.  was that supposed to be  `get_data()`? `printf("                     %.2f", *data);` invalid.

Comment: @Umair your flag was declined. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/9832392?group=1&status=3